# How to insert data in a Graph Tree dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I am trying to insert different kinds of parameters in a Graph method using a loop. Statically I would write the code like this

```
    graph.connect('Station', 'Place1', 6)
    graph.connect('Place1', 'Extension12', 2)
    graph.connect('Place1', 'Extension14', 4)
    graph.connect('Place1', 'Extension17', 6)
    graph.connect('Station', 'Place2', 2)
    graph.connect('Place2', 'Extension13', 6)
    graph.connect('Place2', 'Extension16', 4)
    graph.connect('Place2', 'Extension21', 2)
```

But I want to use a loop to get this data from dictionary and insert it into a `graph` method.

`location = {'Station': 0, Place2': 2, 'Place1': 6}`

`sublocation = {'Extension12': 2, 'Extension14': 4, 'Extension17': 6, 'Extension13': 6, 'Extension16': 4, 'Extension21': 2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to organize data per group. You can do this simply using a nested dictionary with lists. Example:

```
data = {
  "Place1": [
    ["Extension12", 2],
    ["Extension14", 4],   
  ],
  "Place2": [...]
}

for place in data.keys():
    for ext in data[place]:
        graph.connect(place, ext[0], ext[1])
```

This should dynamically add them to the graph. Although I am concerned about the discrepancies in your parameters (Station) but it seems straightforward to deal with.

Comment: The first line of the code got cutoff, I've just edited it now. Let me work with this idea. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @CrozierNtwe Sure, let me know if you run into an issue.